# Chrome Autoplay Policy: What counts as an "interaction"?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom

According to [Google's update on Chrome's Autoplay Policy Changes](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes), autoplay with sound is allowed if "User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.)."

Is there a definitive list of DOM events which are considered by Chrome to be valid "interactions", which will then allow sound to autoplay?

Comment: May I ask why you need them? Are you trying to achieve something or just out of curiosity?

Comment: I'm working on a web-based game which, when logged in, will play audio on some pages. The game is not a single page application and "interactions with the domain" don't seem to carry over between page loads - so, I'm curious to know what my options are to work around this problem.